# Baked lightmap in unity 5.2 not affect on android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have problem with baked lightmap. It works on window + web player. But it doesn't work on Android device. How do I resolve this?

[Picture of editor and Lighting Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gG34.jpg)

[Picture of build settings and result on Android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr008.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is broken on  android devices.  The issue is being tracked as far as I know. In the meantime, these are all the stuffs I tried:
1) Force "Open GL ES 3.0" and use standard shader in the materials.
2) In the quality settings, set the pixel light count to 10.

Hope this helps you out.

Regards.